# iTunes Connect can't edit description

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

The app is approved and "Ready for sale", but there is a lock icon next to Description and I can't make any changes. Other fields like "Promotional Text", "Support URL", etc are editable.

I've read a lot of conflicting and old information about this. Any help would be appreciated

[image: ss]

Comment: editable fields like promotional text and description should not be saved after app ready for sale.can you try by editing and save that information

Comment: I'm trying to edit Description but it's greyed out and has a lock

Comment: They recently changed their policies: With iOS 11 the description is no longer editable. You need to submit a new version for it.

Comment: Apple: letting millions of devs work for them, for free. New in this version of IOS: Pick a bale of cotton for us. It's good exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot able to edit description and few other fields here without Apple’s approval(review), and to edit you have to upload a new version.

References:
https://9to5mac.com/2017/03/09/developers-edit-app-store-descriptions-app-review/
http://wccftech.com/developers-longer-update-app-store-description-apples-approval/

Comment: Per the 9to5mac link, this has been reverted.

Comment: Today I tried to update the description of an app, but it's greyed out and has a lock. Did Apple change it once again?